# ¿Cómo validar en JavaScript si un objeto tiene una propiedad?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el objeto `equis`, y supongamos que quiero el valor `equis.valorFantasma`

Pero yo no se si existe la propiedad `valorFantasma`, ¿cómo valido que exista antes de tomar su valor?

```js
function funcion(){
  //alert('boton presionado');
  
  var existePropiedadFantasma = false;
  
  var equis;
  
  existePropiedadFantasma = typeof equis.propiedadFantasma !== 'undefined';//equis.propiedadFantasma ? true:false;
  
  alert(existePropiedadFantasma ? "Si existe": "No Existe");
}
```

```html
<input type='button' onclick="funcion()" value='Obtener Valor'/>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.  Gracias.

ZIUL... intente con tu respuesta y me sale el mismo error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algún ejemplo que si funcione?

Comment: Por objeto te refieres a un simple `{ }` o a cualquier tipo de objeto en `javascript`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que tu variable `equis` es un `undefined` al momento de declararlo. Asimismo, podrías usar el método [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty) para verificar la existencia de una propiedad.

```js
function TienePropiedad(objeto, propiedad){
  return typeof objeto !== 'undefined' && objeto.hasOwnProperty(propiedad);
}

var equis;

console.log(TienePropiedad(equis, "valorFantasma"));

equis= {};
equis.valorFantasma= "Mi propiedad";

console.log(TienePropiedad(equis, "valorFantasma"));

console.log(equis);
```

**Resultado:**

> ```
> false
> true
> {
>   "valorFantasma": "Mi propiedad"
> }
> ```

Comment: Todas las respuestas están muy completas, pero esta es la que mejor se adapta a mi necesidad muchas gracias :-)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo _Utiliza los comentarios para pedir más información o para sugerir mejoras. Evita los comentarios como “+1” o “gracias”._ [¿Por que no se puede agradecer en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/766/por-que-no-se-puede-agradecer-en-los-comentarios)

Comment: @Davlio: Me parece que el comentario es desde un postura demasiado estricta ya que Cristina está explicando la razón por la cual seleccionó tu respuesta, lo cual me parece si bien no es obligatorio, si es una cortesía realizada de forma apropiada.

Answer (score 7):

Usa `hasOwnProperty()` para comprobar propiedades del objeto, `in` para propiedades heredadas del prototipo.

Ejemplo simple para propiedades del objeto

```js
/**
 * Demostración de verificación de existencia de propiedades en objeto
 *
 */

function demo() { 

  // Crear objeto
  var casa = new Object;

  // Agregar propiedad al objeto
  casa.puerta = {principal: true, traspatio: true, cochera: false};

  // Verificar si el objeto tiene la propiedad puerta (existente)
  var control_puerta = (casa.hasOwnProperty('puerta'))? 'Sí':'No';
  console.log('¿La casa tiene puerta?: ' + control_puerta);

  // Verificar si el objeto tiene la propiedad ventana (inexistente)
  var control_ventana = (casa.hasOwnProperty('ventana'))? 'Sí':'No';
  console.log('¿La casa tiene ventana?: ' + control_ventana) ;
}

demo();
```

Ejemplo para comprobar propiedades heredadas

```js
/**
 * Demostración de verfiación de existencia de propiedades heredadas 
 *
 */

// Crear el objeto 
var casa = function() {
  this.puerta = {principal:true, traspatio:true, cochera:false}
}

function demo() {

  // Crear objeto a partir de otro
  var residencia = new casa();

  // Verificar la existencia de la propiedad puerta (existente)
  var control_puerta = ('puerta' in residencia) ? "Sí" : "No";
  console.log('¿La residencia tiene puerta?: ' + control_puerta);

  // Verificar la existencia de la propiedad ventana (inexistente)
  var control_ventana = ('ventana' in residencia) ? "Sí" : "No";
  console.log('¿La residencia tiene ventana?: ' + control_ventana);  
}

demo();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  Esta muy bien documentada y completa, pero elegí la otra porque es mas simple y en verdad se adapta mas a mi necesidad, mil gracias.

Comment: Entiendo Cristina, y es perfectamente válido. La idea es aportar algo si bien que respondiera la pregunta también que fuera diferente a las otras respuestas.

Answer (score 4):

Es importante tener en cuenta que un objeto puede tener propiedades y funciones, el siguiente ejemplo ilustra como poder validar un objeto adecuadamente:

```js
obj=new Object();
obj.esPropiedad=1;
obj.esFuncion=function(){return 1};
isTypeOf(obj.esPropiedad);
isTypeOf(obj.esFuncion);
isTypeOf(obj.noDefinido);

function isTypeOf(o) {
 is=typeof o
 if (is == "function") {
  console.log("es funcion:"+o());
 } else if (is != "undefined") {
  console.log("es propiedad:"+o);
 } else {
  console.log("no definido:"+o);
 }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

La forma mas completa de hacerlo seria:

```
typeof equis.propiedadFantasma !== 'undefined'
```

Esto funciona aun que sea una propiedad inline inventada, ejemplo:

```
typeof wbefwjhebfwiud !== 'undefined'
```

O si es una propiedad que nunca puede tomar el valor `null`, `0` o `''` se puede validar asi:

```
function existePropiedadFantasma() {
  var _existePropiedadFantasma = !!equis.propiedadFantasma;
  alert(_existePropiedadFantasma ? "Si existe": "No Existe");
}
```

Comment: No funciona o como lo implementarias en mi ejemplo?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar

```
if ("undefined" === typeof equis.valorFantasma){
    console.log('NO EXISTE LA PROPIEDAD')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Una solucion simple es

```
if("propiedad" in objeto)
    console.log("si");
else
    console.log("no");
```